# Laravel 4 occasionally cannot find users table

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel

I have a Laravel app with a standard users table which required authentication. I am using SQL server 2008.

Every now and then I get the following error, usually on AJAX requests and more rarely on page load:

> {"error":{"type":"Illuminate\Database\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[42S02]:
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object
>   name 'users'. (SQL: select top 1 * from [users] where [id] =
>   1)","file":"C:\wamp\www\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php","line":555}}

What baffles me is the inconsistency of this error. The same error repeats itself more rarely with other tables.

What can cause such a peculiar behaviour?

Comment: Are there other applications using the same database? Can you increase the log level to dump ddl statements of all the apps using the database? Can you confirm that it's the right database? Are your queries assembled manually from user input?

Comment: No other apps using this DB. It has to be the right DB as other tables are functioning correctly including the users table most times. Some queries are built manually by user input, but the error is application wide and repeats itself occasionally on every page. I have a method on my base controller that grabs the user data (`Auth::user()`) and sends it as json for JS usage. Maybe this is the problem?